# actual and actually

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is there any practical difference between the following sentences?

> a. That's the actual reason I'm going.
>
> b. That's the reason I'm actually going.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there certainly ***is*** a difference!

Using *the **actual** reason* implies there are other possible justifications for going - but in fact ***that*** is the real one.

Using *I'm **actually** going* implies that I could have responded in other possible ways - for example, I could have phoned or emailed, rather than going somewhere to meet with someone in person.

---

The long and short of it is that by default an adjective such as ***actual***  applies to the noun immediately following (emphasising *that **noun/thing** is the real / relevant one,* not something else). And by the same token, an adverb such as ***actually*** applies to the verb immediately following (emphasising *that **verb/action** is the real / relevant one*).